# VBA Access MouseHook Wrapper

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-api-code-pack, mouse-hook

So, my main goal is to be able to move / resize the main access window along with a popup form, that is, when the main form is moved/resized, i want the main window to follow. So, with the help of some online code and chatgpt i've narrowed it down to the following code (i have to use this approach since any other doesn't help - if i start with the main window hidden, the popup menus and the non popup forms don't show - obviously since the window is hidden)

1. PUBLIC MODULE (mdl_MouseHook)
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

   ```
    Public Type MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        PT As POINTAPI
        MouseData As Long
        Flags As Long
        time As Long
        dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
    End Type

    Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hhk As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hhk As LongPtr) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As LongPtr
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long
    Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowTextLengthA Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr) As Long


    Public Const WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
    Public Const HC_ACTION = 0
    Public Const WM_MOUSEMOVE = &H200
    Public Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN = &H201
    Public Const WM_RBUTTONDOWN = &H204
    Public Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20A
    Public Const WM_LBUTTONUP = &H202
    Public Const WM_RBUTTONUP = &H205

    Public cHook As clsMouseHook
    Public hHook As LongPtr
    Public lHook As Object

    Public isMouseDown As Boolean
    Public isMouseMoved As Boolean

    ' Put your own hook processing here:
    Public Function LowLevelMouseProc(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT) As LongPtr
    Const CPN = "mdl_MouseHook\LowLevelMouseProc"

    On Error GoTo Eroare

    Dim currentHwnd As LongPtr

    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
        If cHook Is Nothing Then
            LowLevelMouseProc = CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)

        ElseIf cHook.HookedForms.Count = 0 Then
            LowLevelMouseProc = CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)

        Else
            currentHwnd = GetForegroundWindow

            Select Case wParam
                Case WM_LBUTTONDOWN
                    isMouseDown = True
                    cHook.MouseDown currentHwnd, 1, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y

                Case WM_LBUTTONUP
                    If isMouseDown And isMouseMoved Then
                        cHook.MouseUp currentHwnd, 1, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y, True

                    ElseIf isMouseDown And Not isMouseMoved Then
                        cHook.MouseUp currentHwnd, 1, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y, False

                    End If

                    isMouseDown = False
                    isMouseMoved = False

                Case WM_RBUTTONDOWN
                    cHook.MouseDown currentHwnd, 2, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y
                Case WM_RBUTTONUP
                    cHook.MouseUp currentHwnd, 2, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y, False
                Case WM_MOUSEWHEEL
                    cHook.MouseWheel currentHwnd, 0, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y, lParam.MouseData
                Case Else
                    If isMouseDown And Not isMouseMoved Then
                        isMouseMoved = True
                        cHook.MouseMove currentHwnd, 0, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y, True

                    ElseIf isMouseDown And isMouseMoved Then
                        cHook.MouseDrag currentHwnd, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y

                    Else
                        cHook.MouseMove currentHwnd, 0, lParam.PT.X, lParam.PT.Y, False

                    End If
            End Select

            LowLevelMouseProc = CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)

        End If
    End If


    Exit Function

    Eroare:
    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
    LowLevelMouseProc = CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam)
    End Function
   ```
2. The form subclass (clsIHook):
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

   ```
        Private FRM As Access.Form

        Public Parent As clsMouseHook
        Private frmHwnd As LongPtr

        Public Property Get HookedForm() As Access.Form
        Set HookedForm = FRM

        End Property

        Public Property Set HookedForm(accForm As Access.Form)
        Set FRM = accForm

        frmHwnd = FRM.hwnd

        End Property
   ```
3. The wrapper class (clsMouseHook):
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

   ```
    Private colHooks As Collection
    Private hasLog As Boolean
    Private curHwnd As LongPtr

    Public hHook As LongPtr

    Private blnIshooked As Boolean

    Public Event FormMouseUp(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, WasDragged As Boolean)
    Public Event FormMouseDown(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long)
    Public Event FormMouseMove(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, IsDragging As Boolean)
    Public Event FormMouseDrag(hwnd As LongPtr, X As Long, Y As Long)

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set colHooks = New Collection
    hasLog = Init_lHook

    End Sub

    Public Property Get HookedForms() As Collection
    Set HookedForms = colHooks
    End Property

    Public Property Get IsHooked() As Boolean
    IsHooked = blnIshooked

    End Property

    Public Sub RegisterForm(FRM As Access.Form)
    Dim iHook As New clsIHook

    Set iHook.HookedForm = FRM

    colHooks.Add iHook

    End Sub

    Public Sub UnregisterForm(FRM As Access.Form)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To colHooks.Count
        If colHooks(i).Parent Is FRM Then
            colHooks.Remove i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    End Sub

    Public Sub Hook()
    Const CPN = "mdl_MouseHook\SetHook"

    On Error GoTo Eroare

    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf LowLevelMouseProc, 0, 0)

    If hHook = 0 Then
        Err.Raise 5, , "An error creating the hook"
    Else
        blnIshooked = True

    End If

    IESIRE:
    Exit Sub

    Eroare:
        If hasLog Then lHook.WriteLine Now() & " " & Err.Description, CPN, Erl
        Resume IESIRE

    End Sub

    Public Sub Unhook(Optional WithError As Boolean = False)
    Const CPN = "mdl_MouseHook\UnhookHandler"

    On Error GoTo Eroare

    UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
    Set colHooks = Nothing

    lHook.WriteLine Now() & " Mouse hook removed " & hHook & IIf(WithError, " with error!", "")

    hHook = 0

    Exit Sub

    Eroare:
        lHook.WriteLine Now() & " " & Err.Description & " " & CPN
    End Sub

    Private Function Init_lHook() As Boolean
    Const CPN = "mdl_MouseHook\Init_lHook"
    ADD_TRACE CPN

    On Error GoTo Eroare

    If glFSO Is Nothing Then Set glFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
    With glFSO
        If Not .FolderExists(CurrentProject.Path & "\LOGS") Then .CreateFolder CurrentProject.Path & "\LOGS"

        If Not .FileExists(CurrentProject.Path & "\LOGS\" & "MHK_log-" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".txt") Then
            Set lHook = .CreateTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\LOGS\" & "MHK_log-" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".txt", False, True)

        ElseIf lHook Is Nothing Then
    '        .Close 'CurrentProject.Path & "\LOGS\" & "log-" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".txt"
            Set lHook = .OpenTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\LOGS\" & "MHK_log-" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".txt", 8, False, -1)

        Else
            lHook.Close
            Set lHook = .OpenTextFile(CurrentProject.Path & "\LOGS\" & "MHK_log-" & Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".txt", 8, False, -1)

        End If
    End With

    Init_lHook = True

    IESIRE:
    REM_TRACE CPN
    Exit Function

    Eroare:
        MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, GET_TRACE
        Resume IESIRE

    End Function

    Private Function GetWindowTitle(hwnd As LongPtr) As String
        Dim length As Long
        Dim title As String

        length = GetWindowTextLengthA(hwnd) + 1
        title = Space$(length)

        Call GetWindowTextA(hwnd, title, length)

        GetWindowTitle = Left$(title, length - 1)
    End Function

    Public Sub MouseUp(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, WasDragged As Boolean)
    RaiseEvent FormMouseUp(hwnd, Button, X, Y, WasDragged)

    End Sub

    Public Sub MouseDown(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long)
    RaiseEvent FormMouseDown(hwnd, Button, X, Y)

    End Sub

    Public Sub MouseMove(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, IsDragging As Boolean)
    RaiseEvent FormMouseMove(hwnd, Button, X, Y, IsDragging)

    End Sub

    Public Sub MouseDrag(hwnd As LongPtr, X As Long, Y As Long)
    RaiseEvent FormMouseDrag(hwnd, X, Y)

    End Sub

    Public Sub MouseWheel(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, MouseData As Long)

    End Sub
   ```
4. Called like so in the deisred form:
   Private WithEvents frmHook As clsMouseHook
   Private TitleBarWasPressed As Boolean
   Private FormIsResized As Boolean

   ```
    Private Sub Form_Close()
    cHook.UnregisterForm Me
    cHook.Unhook
    Set cHook = Nothing
    Set frmHook = Nothing

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set cHook = New clsMouseHook
    Set frmHook = cHook
        cHook.RegisterForm Me
        cHook.Hook
    End Sub


    Private Sub frmHook_FormMouseDown(hwnd As LongPtr, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long)
    Dim rc As RECT

    GetWindowRect Me.hwnd, rc

    If hwnd = Me.hwnd Then
        If Y > rc.Y1 And Y < rc.Y1 + 30 Then
            Debug.Print "Title bar is pressed "
            TitleBarWasPressed = True
        ElseIf X > rc.X2 - 10 And X < rc.X2 Then
            Debug.Print "Left edge was pressed"
            FormIsResized = True
        Else
            Debug.Print "MOUSE: " & X & "," & Y & "; FORM: " & rc.X2 & "," & rc.Y2
        End If

    End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmHook_FormMouseDrag(hwnd As LongPtr, X As Long, Y As Long)
    If TitleBarWasPressed Then
        Debug.Print "Titlebar is dragging"

    ElseIf FormIsResized Then
        Debug.Print "Form width is resizing"

    End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub frmHook_FormMouseUp(hwnd As LongLong, Button As Long, X As Long, Y As Long, WasDragged As Boolean)
    If WasDragged Then
        If TitleBarWasPressed Then
            TitleBarWasPressed = False
            Debug.Print "Form was moved @" & X & "," & Y

        ElseIf FormIsResized Then
            FormIsResized = False
            Debug.Print "Form was resized @" & X & "," & Y
        End If

    End If

    End Sub
   ```

The problem with it is that sometimes it crashes randomly. Do you have any idea why and what i can do about it?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you add breakpoints to see where it crashes ? Maybe create a log table to see what the values where at the moment of the crash, the current methode etc. Also you can add error handling in your code.  Example : 

Private Sub cmdDeleteRecord_Click()
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
HandleExit:
    Exit Sub
HandleError:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume HandleExit
End Sub

Source : https://www.codevba.com/help/error_handling.htm

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, but: breakpoint and hooks don't go together (not in vba, at least), i have a log exactly for that which logs the critical parts of the procedures, i have error control where it's needed (not everywhere), so the problem i'm thinking, is from the interaction with other windows hooks, but i just don't know how to get to those :(

Comment: can you add the error handling to every procedure ? If you wan't you can send me the access file via we transfer and i can take a look on my pc. My email is on my profile.

Comment: I will try to add error handler everywhere and keep you posted. I don't want to bother you with the code, but I'll try the suggestion 